# How to remove the column in specific value using java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make 2D array that Na removed.
If NA is in fifth column and second row, then I want to remove second row. 
my code's step]
1step: data loading (1D array)
2step: make 2D array
3step: find specific value's column and row
4step: its row remove from array

but result is so bad..
help me

```
public static String[][] removeNA(String[][] str,int varNumber){
    String deleteMe="NA";
    String[][] na2Arr= new String[varNumber][str.length/varNumber]; 
            for(int i=0;i<varNumber;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<str.length/varNumber;j++){
                String  tmp=str[i][j];
                if(tmp.equals(deleteMe))//참이면 [i,j] 중 j가 포함된거 모두 제거
                    {
                    for(int k=0;k<varNumber;k++){
                        String tmp1=str[k][j+1];
                        na2Arr[k][j]=tmp1;
                            }
                        }
                else{
                    for(int k=0;k<varNumber;k++){
                        String tmp1=str[k][j];
                        na2Arr[k][j]=tmp1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                return na2Arr;
        }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = readCSV(new File("D:/sample2.csv"));
    String[] strArr = parse(str); // String 배열에 차곡차곡 담겨서 나온다.
    int varNumber = 45;
    int rowNumber = strArr.length/varNumber;
    String[][] Array2D = new String[varNumber][rowNumber];


    for(int i=0; i<rowNumber;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<varNumber;j++)
            {
                String k = strArr[i*varNumber+j];
                        Array2D[j][i]= k;
            }
    }
    String[][] naArray2D=removeNA(Array2D,varNumber);

    /*      for(int i=0; i<naArray1D.length;i++){
        System.out.println(naArray1D[i]);
        }*/
                for(int i=0;i<varNumber;i++){
                        for(int j=0;j<naArray2D.length/varNumber;j++){
                            System.out.println(naArray2D[i][j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println("**********************N A제거&2차원 배열**********************");
                }


}
```

Comment: So if you have a `String[45][10]` and one cell contains `NA`, then you want to remove that column so you get a `String[45][9]`, is that it?

Comment: Is it possible that there are more than one such column that should be removed? Could you end up having no columns at all?

Comment: Thx for your reply and Your question about having more than 1 column removed and no column at all is possible if there exist more than 1 NA need to be removed

Comment: Related: [how to delete 2D array column in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799356/how-to-delete-2d-array-column-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it:

```
public static String[][] removeNA(String[][] str, int varNumber) {
    String[][] na2Arr = new String[str.length][varNumber];
    // iterate over columns in str
    int columnsCopied = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < varNumber; col++) {
        if (! columnContainsNa(col, str)) {
            // copy column to result
            for (int row = 0; row < str.length; row++) {
                na2Arr[row][columnsCopied] = str[row][col];
            }
            columnsCopied++;
        }
    }
    if (columnsCopied < varNumber) {
        // shorten each inner array to the actual number of columns (leave out if you don’t want this)
        for (int row = 0; row < str.length; row++) {
            na2Arr[row] = Arrays.copyOf(na2Arr[row], columnsCopied);
        }
    }
    return na2Arr;
}

private static boolean columnContainsNa(int col, String[][] str) {
    String deleteMe = "NA";
    for (int row = 0; row < str.length; row++) {
        if (str[row][col].equals(deleteMe)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I changed variable names `i` and `j` to `row` and `col`, I think it’s easier to read this way. The `columnsCopied` variable makes sure each column is copied into the right column of the result array even when more columns contain `NA` and are deleted. Also I think it’s simpler with the auxiliary method, `columnContainsNa`.

Please remember to mark the answer as accepted (on the tick mark to the left) if you think it is correct and helpful.

Comment: thank you for your answer and kindness..there are a small problem...your answer reverse the column and rows, I am trying to fix the problem.. but it doesn't go well..

Comment: In that case I misunderstood. So if you have a `String[45][10]` and one cell contains NA, then you want to remove that column so you get a `String[44][10]`, is that it?

Comment: uh.. I set array to array[varNumber][data.length/varNumber]

Comment: Is `varNumber` the number of rows or the number of columns? If you will excuse me, you could use a better variable name.

Comment: uh.. I set array to array[varNumber][data.length/varNumber] . so if NA value exist in array[5][2], then remove the array[.][2]. therefore array is array[varNumber][(data.length/varNumber)-1]. varNumber is constant.

Comment: Alright. If I understand correctly now, I think it’s just that I used the wrong naming: I called the row number `col` and the column nunber `row`. Switch around the variable names. I believe the code behaves correctly. If not, please be specific about the desired and observed behaviour and the differemce between the two and I will have another look.

Comment: I'll try that. thank you!! your answer help really to me!!

Comment: Thank you. I solve the problem!! length is number of row in 2D array. so I revise col and row. so code do well work. thank you!!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Thanks for reporting that.